# Excel LEFT and IF

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Mostly all fields begin with the name and address, but some fields start with a number. I would like to have the address removed leaving only the full name, which I do have the formula and it works perfectly. At the same time, if the field begins with a number, I would like it to be blank. How can I combine the `LEFT` formula with an `IF` statement? My current formula is:

```
=LEFT(AD45,FIND(" ",AD45,FIND(" ",AD45)+1)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the fields that begin with numbers actually number fields or text fields that start with a number?

If they are number fields I would use the ISTEXT function

```
=IF(ISTEXT(AD45), LEFT(AD45,FIND(" ",AD45,FIND(" ",AD45)+1)-1), " ")
```